# cordova on linux cant find build tools

Tags: android, linux, path

This must be a path issue but I can't seem to get it fixed. Online help is a bit confusing since answers for Windows, Mac, and Linux show up. Running Opensuse 15.3

To be specific I am trying to build this apk:
[apk for TTGO](https://github.com/dl9rdz/rdzwx-go)
I don't think the issue is with the github source but my system.

I have set these environment variables:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/mrg//Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/home/mrg/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/mrg/Android/Sdk/build-tools:/home/mrg/Android/Sdk/build-tools/33.0.0-rc1:.
```

Testing the environment variables:

```
echo $PATH
/home/mrg/.local/bin:/home/mrg/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/kde3/bin:/home/mrg/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/mrg/Android/Sdk/build-tools:/home/mrg/Android/Sdk/build-tools/33.0.0-rc1:.
echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
/home/mrg//Android/Sdk
```

Building the apk:

```
cordova build
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/mrg//Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/mrg/Android/Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/mrg/android/rdzwx-go/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 69

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/mrg/android/rdzwx-go/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/mrg/android/rdzwx-go/platforms/android/build.gradle
```

Comment: I've managed to fix this in android studio menu     
TOOLS > SDK Manager     
Open tab SDK Tools     
Click on Android SDK Build tools XX item  (first item from the list)     
CHECK SHOW PACKAGE DETAILS in bottom right corrner     
Now you see all packaged      
I've selected all from 30.x.x.x.     
APPLY

Comment: They were already selected. I upgraded to the latest build tools but still no difference.

Comment: can you try to use 30.0.3 version?